# Counting number of digits in a double C++

Tags: c++

I'm using a while loop to count the number of digits in my input.

So my input was 1.525

```
length = 0;
num = num - int(num);
while ( num >= .0001 ) {
    num = num * 10;
    length = length + 1;
    num = num - int(num); }
```

When i do

```
cout << "\n\nLength: " << length << "\n";
```

The answer I get is 51 and other numbers give me an asnwear of 49 or something that is obviously wrong.
Is it the way c++ works or is it just my mistake. Thank you.

Comment: You can see what's happening by displaying the values as your algo runs: http://ideone.com/ORPWpx - keep in mind the already-given background information that `double`s can't store 1.525 precisely.

Answer (score 2):

`double` and `float` can't always hold precisely the values you try to store in them, thats not how they work. In many cases they will store an approximate value, that usually can be rounded up to what you meant to store there in the first place, but not exactly. Thats why you are getting those results.

Answer (score 2):

You can use string or char array to store the the number inputed.  it can precisely count the length. float double store a  approximate value, you can reference [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format).

Comment: Good lead, though worth keeping in mind corner cases - when inputting a `double` 1.525, 1.5250 and 0.1525E1 could well be equivalent, but with strings it's a bit unclear what the answer should be, and the processing to get that answer can be a bit trickier.

Answer (score 0):

Floating point numbers cannot store the decimal 1.525 precisely but if you use `round` instead of int cast and use `fabs` when comparing against the tolerance to protect against negative numbers you will get something you might be happy with:

```
num -= round(num);
while(fabs(num) >= .0001) {
  num *= 10;
  ++length;
  num -= round(num); 
}
```

If you are happy to accept that 1.9999999 has the same number of digits as 2.0.

Generally, trying to find the number of digits in a floating point number is going to be a bit meaningless because it is not stored as decimal digits.